# vba unable to read timestamp field from oracle

Tags: sql, excel, vba, oracle

I have a query "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER" in the customer table I have one of the data type is TIMESTAMP(6) when try to retrieve the data from excel vba i am getting error.  How do I convert timestamp to character if I am using *?

```
Set objConn = CreateObject("OracleInProcServer.XOraSession")
Set objDB = objConn.DbOpenDatabase("myDB", "UserID/Pass", 0)
strTBLQuery = "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER"
Set rsTBLData = objDB.DbCreateDynaset(strTBLQuery, CInt(0))
Do While Not rsTBLData.EOF
    'I am getting "Object does not support this property or method" error for rsTBLData(i).value when it comes to date/timestamp field.
    strCellVal = rsTBLData(i).Value
Loop
```

Comment: And the error message is?

Comment: And the timestamp looks like?

Comment: *Show your code*, the exact error you get, and anything else you think might be useful (Oracle version, oracle client version, exact driver used, etc)

Comment: Set objConn = CreateObject("OracleInProcServer.XOraSession")
Set objDB = objConn.DbOpenDatabase("myDB", "UserID/Pass",0)  
strTBLQuery = "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER"
Set rsTBLData  = objDB.DbCreateDynaset(strTBLQuery, cint(0))

         Do While Not rsTBLData.EOF
               strCellVal = rsTBLData(i).value 
         Loop

I am getting "Object does not support this property or method" error for rsTBLData(i).value when it comes to date/timestamp field.

Comment: Please edit the question itself.  Don't put important information in comments.

Answer (score 0):

For timestamp values i think you will need:

```
strCellVal = rsTBLData(i).Value.toDate
```

The field's `Value` property is an object itself, which in turn has methods...

http://k613.fd.cvut.cz/personal/jerabem1/14ndb/dokumentace_Oracle_11-2/win.112/e17727/advfeat.htm#OOFOL239

Comment: ok thanks I ended up using java. I will check in vbs and let post my result.